# How to display whole data from database

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display the whole data present in database in front end. I could not get how to display it in front end. However I can display a single row with the help of id. The given below is what I did

```
<?php
    $test_id = 3;
    $model = Mage::getModel('test/test')->load($test_id);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->gettest_id().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->gettitle().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->getfilename().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->getcontent().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->getstatus().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->getcreated_time().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$model->getupdate_time().'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
 ?>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to display the whole data from database.
Thanx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<?php
    $collection= Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $model){
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->gettest_id().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->gettitle().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->getfilename().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->getcontent().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->getstatus().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->getcreated_time().'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$model->getupdate_time().'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: its giving error bro.  (failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
)

Comment: where you have placed code and do you have test model?

Comment: I placed it here /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/models/template/test

Comment: models is your theme name?

Comment: yes it is my module name

Comment: its working now, I don't have collection file. I created it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

use `getCollection()` method of Model.

Comment: can u brief it please..

Answer (score 2):

Use this code :

```
<?php
$model = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
foreach($model as $data)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getTestId().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getTitle().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getFilename().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getContent().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getStatus().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getCreatedTime().'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$data->getUpdateTime().'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
 ?>
```

Comment: giving error bro (failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magento/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94)

Comment: @Birju Where you are putting this code. Also is your previous code is working with id ?

Comment: here  /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/models/tem‌​plate/test  models is my module name. And yes it is working with id

Comment: its working now, I don't have collection file. I created it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Collection model of that model**

```
$collection->getCollection();
```

Then  add to collection 
`addFieldToFilter('*')` for all fields  values.**`*`** use for *all fields value*

```
$collection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('*') ;
```

Then use

`$collection->getData()` which give an array with result

Answer (score 1):

You can execute direct select query as shown below:

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$table = $resource->getTableName('test/test'); //here you should use resource entity name. 
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$table}";
$rows = $readConnection->fetchAll($query); 
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example is here man.

```
$collection= Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
    // you can use this print_r command to check if you getting data in collection.
    print_r($collection);

    if(count($collection)>0){
     foreach($collection as $coll){
     // use PHP Magic functions to get values.
      echo $coll->getTitle(); 
     }
    }
```